# BitOperations.IsPow2 unbalanced benchmark

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, .net-6.0, benchmarkdotnet

I am benchmarking the method [`BitOperations.IsPow2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.ispow2?view=net-6.0) with `BenchmarkDotNet`, but the results I got were far from my expectations. Here is the minimal code you need to reproduce the benchmark:

**PowerOf2Benchmark.cs**

```
using System.Numerics;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

public class PowerOf2Benchmark {
    [Params(2048, 10003457, 20000123, 16777216)]
    public int n;

    [Benchmark]
    public bool CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn() 
    {
        return BitOperations.IsPow2(n);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<PowerOf2Benchmark>();
```

And here is the summary of the benchmark:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=ubuntu 20.04
Intel Core i5-6200U CPU 2.30GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 2 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.202
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT


|                        Method |        n |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Code Size |
|------------------------------ |--------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn |     2048 | 0.0955 ns | 0.0092 ns | 0.0081 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 10003457 | 1.1815 ns | 0.0046 ns | 0.0040 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 16777216 | 0.1000 ns | 0.0054 ns | 0.0051 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 20000123 | 1.1750 ns | 0.0126 ns | 0.0112 ns |      28 B |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  PowerOf2Benchmark.CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed (2.33 ns)
  PowerOf2Benchmark.CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed (3.38 ns)
  PowerOf2Benchmark.CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed (3.42 ns)
```

I hope I interpreted the results correctly, but **it seems that `BitOperations.IsPow2` is more than 10x faster when `n` is a power of 2 (2048, 16777216)  compared to when it is not (10003457, 20000123). Why is that?**

---

The [source code of `BitOperations.IsPow2`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BitOperations.cs,46) should be this one:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static bool IsPow2(int value) => (value & (value - 1)) == 0 && value > 0;
```

I am also assuming the `AggressiveInlining` optimization is not the reason for the unbalanced results. I am not an expert on hardware optimizations either, but the ASM code produced is quite simple (it is inlined because of `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`):

```
; CheckIfNumberIsPowerOf2.PowerOf2Benchmark.CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn()
       push      rbp
       mov       rbp,rsp
       mov       eax,[rdi+8]
       lea       edi,[rax-1]
       test      edi,eax
       jne       short M00_L01
       test      eax,eax
       setg      al
       movzx     eax,al
M00_L00:
       pop       rbp
       ret
M00_L01:
       xor       eax,eax
       jmp       short M00_L00
; Total bytes of code 28
```

---

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity, I have created a class containing a method with the same implementation of `BitOperations.IsPow2`:

```
static public class PowerOf2Verifier
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static public bool CheckWithBitMaskV3(int n) => (n & (n - 1)) == 0 && n > 0;
}
```

Then, in the `PowerOf2Benchmark` class, I have added this method:

```
[Benchmark]
public bool CheckWithBitMaskV3() 
{
    return PowerOf2Verifier.CheckWithBitMaskV3(n);
}
```

This is the updated summary:

```
|                        Method |        n |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Code Size |
|------------------------------ |--------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|            CheckWithBitMaskV3 |     2048 | 0.5141 ns | 0.0098 ns | 0.0087 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn |     2048 | 0.1040 ns | 0.0085 ns | 0.0079 ns |      28 B |
|            CheckWithBitMaskV3 | 10003457 | 0.3589 ns | 0.0091 ns | 0.0081 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 10003457 | 1.1824 ns | 0.0091 ns | 0.0081 ns |      28 B |
|            CheckWithBitMaskV3 | 16777216 | 0.5143 ns | 0.0063 ns | 0.0059 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 16777216 | 0.0991 ns | 0.0076 ns | 0.0071 ns |      28 B |
|            CheckWithBitMaskV3 | 20000123 | 0.4513 ns | 0.0190 ns | 0.0177 ns |      28 B |
| CheckWithBitOperationsBuiltIn | 20000123 | 1.1257 ns | 0.0108 ns | 0.0090 ns |      28 B |
```

In this case, `CheckWithBitMaskV3` results are consistent, and this surprises me even more because the two methods I am benchmarking are implemented in the same way now. What could be the explanation?

---

**EDIT 2**

For some reason, the assembly of `CheckWithBitMaskV3` is slightly different from that of `IsPow2`:

```
; CheckIfNumberIsPowerOf2.PowerOf2Benchmark.CheckWithBitMaskV3()
       push      rbp
       mov       rbp,rsp
       mov       eax,[rdi+8]
       lea       edi,[rax-1]
       test      edi,eax
       jne       short M00_L00
       test      eax,eax
       setg      al
       movzx     eax,al
       jmp       short M00_L01
M00_L00:
       xor       eax,eax
M00_L01:
       pop       rbp
       ret
; Total bytes of code 28
```

Comment: Your compiler must be optimizing away some of the loop; unless your CPU runs at 10GHz, an average time per operation of 0.1 ns is significantly less than 1 clock cycle.  Skylake can run [`blsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr) at 2/clock (https://uops.info), which implements the same `n & (n-1)` check your asm is doing with `lea` / `test`, and as a bonus sets CF=1 if the input was zero (similar to what your asm is checking with `test eax,eax`/`setg`).  But `blsr` alone don't materializing a boolean result anywhere, and no sign this code is using it. And it wouldn't reject all negatives

Comment: IDK, you could imagine a compiler deciding it was unrolling by 4 or something, then optimizing away all the work inside the loop.  (Hoisting it and doing it once).  Then timing an empty loop and counting each clock cycle as 4 operations.  `1/2.6GHz / 4 = 0.096 ns` if your CPU wan't at full 2.8GHz turbo.  I thought Benchmarkdotnet was supposed to avoid that kind of nonsense, but a bug might be possible.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes for the interest and the info. I have edited the question and, honestly, I am even more confused than before.

Comment: @PeterCordes The C# code of `CheckWithBitMaskV3` and `IsPow2` is the same, but the assembly generated is slightly different.

Comment: You're still just showing asm for a stand-alone function, not inlined into a loop.  If anything weird is happening, it's happening after inlining, because it's impossible that more than 1 function call per clock cycle could execute.  Nor could a Skylake run that many instructions per clock cycle; its front-end is only 4 wide.  (Of course, inlining would get rid of the pass by reference indirection, but it's still multiple instructions.)